# Qt QTcpSocket waitForReadyRead crashes when socket is closed from a different thread

Tags: qt

- I am calling waitForReadyRead method of QTcpSocket in a separate thread(pthread) ,
- Now if socket is closed from the main thread the application crashes in waitForReadyRead method.

And I am using waitForReadyRead  with time out = -1.

Also I cannot use qt signal slot mechanism in my implementation

Can someone Please explain me what is wrong in the above implementation

Comment: Ofcourse it does! QTcpSocket itself is not thread safe! You may use socket in only one thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Qt documentation of QTcpThread](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtcpsocket.html):

> Note: All functions in this class are reentrant.

This means that it is not safe to call one object from multiple threads (read [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/threads-reentrancy.html#reentrant) for more info). Even if you get your code to work somehow it might crash in an older or newer version.

If you really can't use signals/slots then you could set a flag when you want to close the connection and call waitForReadyRead in a loop with a timeout. Then you can poll the flag and close the socket with the waitForReadyRead-thread if it is set.